# Monaco: always show suggestion descriptions

Tags: monaco-editor

I've been endlessly digging through the docs and code but I couldn't find if it's possible to always show suggestion descriptions by default?

[image: Descriptions by default]

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion descriptions are displayed if you set a value for `detail`.
[See here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/35eb0efbc039827432002ccc17b120eb0874d70f/website/typedoc/monaco.d.ts#L6227)